# Smart Contract runs external API

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I want to create a smart contract that can run API and I don't want to use chainlink so is it possible to do that without using it?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to call external API endpoints from the EVM.

However, you can use a similar pattern to what Chainlink is using, with the difference of being more centralized. You can have an off-chain app listening to specific transfers or events.

When the off-chain app catches this transfer or event, it can call the external API. And then pass the result of the call back to your contract, in a form of a transaction executing a contract function, passing it the returned data (the same way as Chainlink does).